# asp.net c# visual studio 2010 issue with sending email- button does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, smtp

Hi i have a trouble sending email from form, my button does not do anything, please help! I've tried different solutions, and smtp setting ports and still does not work, any help would be really appreciated
here's my code:

```
      Aspx side:

      <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style2
        {
            width: 341px;
        }
    </style>
        </asp:Content>
      <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
      Test
    </h2>
    <p>
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
              <p>
        Please Fill the Following to Send Mail.</p>
              <p>
        Your name:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server"   ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="YourName" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourName" runat="server" Width="250px" /><br />
        Your email address:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="YourEmail" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourEmail" runat="server" Width="250px" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator23"
            SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Example: username@gmail.com" ControlToValidate="YourEmail"
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic"
            ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        Subject:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="YourSubject" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourSubject" runat="server" Width="400px" /><br />
        Your Question:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="Comments" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" 
                TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="400px" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" 
                    OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="save" />
    </p>
</asp:Panel>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="DisplayMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
</p>  `enter code here`
</asp:Content>


and cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void SendMail()
    {


  // your email address
 var fromAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString();
 // any address where the email will be sending
 var toAddress = "my email address";

        //Password of your gmail address
        const string toPassword = "my password";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(toAddress, toPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //here on button click what will done 
            SendMail();
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Your Comments after sending the mail";
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            YourSubject.Text = "";
            YourEmail.Text = "";
            YourName.Text = "";
            Comments.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting a breakpoint and stepping through each line?

Comment: i don't get any errors, it is just loading for 2mins then does nowt